# Load images only 'once' into UICollectionView cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, uicollectionview

I subclassed `UIImageView` to load images asynchronously, to not effect `UICollectionView` scroll performance. Although this does work, it scrolls fluently and the images are not duplicated, it `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` every time a user scrolls up or down. Im wondering if its possible to only load the image once and not have a constant call to get data while scrolling. I am using Parse for a database.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
albumImageCell *cell = (albumImageCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[albumImageCell alloc]init];
    }


    PFObject *temp = [_dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    PFFile *file = [temp objectForKey:@"imageThumbnail"];

    [cell.imageView setFile:file];

    return cell;
}
```

---

Custom ImageView -

```
- (void) setFile:(PFFile *)file {

    NSString *requestURL = file.url; // Save copy of url locally (will not change in block)
    [self setUrl:file.url]; // Save copy of url on the instance

    self.image = nil;
    [file getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"GETTING DATA AGAIN");
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
                //Background Thread
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                    //UI Updates
                    if ([requestURL isEqualToString:self.url]) {
                        [self setImage:image];
                        [self setNeedsDisplay];
                    }
                });
            });
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error on fetching file");
        }
    }];
}
```

Possibly something in `preparseForReuse`? And Ive also tried things like `if(image == nil)` then load data, but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to use `SDWebImage` for this purpose. It's a bulletproofed library which takes care of downloading and caching web-images. It also cancels runnings requests if you scroll to the list very fast.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage